# swift 3 fade image, not UIImage layer

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I'm wondering if its possible to animate the view inside of a UIImageView without animating the UIImageView's layer. I'm wanting the border to not animate, and the image to clip to the border, but for the image to fade in and out as needed.

I'm animating like this:

```
func animateStart() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
        self.firstImg.image = UIImage(named:"peter.JPG")
        self.firstImg.alpha = 1
    }, completion: { finished in
        if finished {
            self.animateSecond()
        }
    })
}
```

Setting borders like:

```
class RoundedImage: UIImageView {

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.layer.borderWidth = 5
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    self.clipsToBounds = true
  }
```

Comment: I guess you cannot do that. Add your imageView as a subview to a UIView of same size which has a border configured. And animate your image view inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make the border on the image view.

Put the border on a UIView and add the image view to that.

Now when you animate the image view and fade it out. The view that it is inside will remain.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really liking this solution. I can't believe how many courses I've taken online and none of them have gone over UIView. Now that I've used one, seems like a fundamental design aspect

Comment: They are very good for creating custom behaviour like this. UIImageView is just one custom behaviour of UIView. Instead of subclass I got UIImageView you could instead subclass UIView to create your container with an image view already in it. Now you have a single view that has a border and can display a fadeable image :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use A UIView(as a container of your imageView) and put your imageView inside of it.make whatever animation you want into that imageView(Fade in Fade out).

And you will get imageView frame(Actually it's not, behind it was UIView which served as a container of your imageView)

**Before Fade:**

[image]

**After Fade**

[image]

**View hierarchy:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer